# How to get usefull stack trace from apache mod_mono?

Tags: asp.net, apache, mod-mono

I'm running apache server on Ubuntu, and I'm trying to get a asp site to run. When I go into a page I get a 404 with the following stack trace:

```
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x0021a] in <dca3b561b8ad4f9fb10141d81b39ff45>:0  
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in <dca3b561b8ad4f9fb10141d81b39ff45>:0  
at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)  
at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in <dca3b561b8ad4f9fb10141d81b39ff45>:0  
at Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.get_CompilerName () [0x00019] in <fa43aae1d96f44db88d3b8a258fd9425>:0  
at Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.FromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00168] in <fa43aae1d96f44db88d3b8a258fd9425>:0  
at Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.Compiler.CompileAssemblyFromFileBatch (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00048] in <fa43aae1d96f44db88d3b8a258fd9425>:0  
at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile (System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options, System.String[] fileNames) [0x00014] in <59be416de143456b88b9988284f43350>:0  
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters options) [0x002f5] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0  
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00008] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0  
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group, System.Web.VirtualPath vp, System.Boolean debug) [0x00264] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0  
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildInner (System.Web.VirtualPath vp, System.Boolean debug) [0x0011c] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0  
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Build (System.Web.VirtualPath vp) [0x00063] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0  
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00040] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0  
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath, System.Type requiredBaseType) [0x00012] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0  
at System.Web.UI.PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance (System.String virtualPath, System.String inputFile, System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00024] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0  
at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String requestType, System.String url, System.String path) [0x00000] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0  
at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String url, System.Boolean ignoreContextHandler) [0x00065] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0  
at System.Web.HttpApplication.GetHandler (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.String url) [0x00000] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0  
at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x0086b] in <d3ba84a338d241e2ab5397407351c9cd>:0
```

This stack trace doen't really help me - there is no data as to what line, what parameters where send to the function, and in total - I don't know what resource is missing.

How can I get a better stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/).

They have a module for the Apache server called «mod_mono».

Hope this helps.

Try the [Mod.Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/)

This handles ASP.NET 4.0 (with the exception of Entity Framework).

See the [compatibility](http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility) for more information on what Mono is compatible with.

Comment: I'm using mod_mono, that's the reason I get a page and not downloading the file. I get this useless stacktrace despite mod_mono.